# ansible: difference between a variable and a fact

Tags: ansible, variables

While I'm using Ansible for quite some time, I'm not sure I really understand the differences between a variable and a fact.
Could someone explain me, possibly with an example where it really make a difference ?

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html):

> Variables related to remote systems are called facts.

Apart on how facts are discovered they are just variables.

It doesn't make any difference.